# In GORM, Object is not modified in database when the object property is modified at Controller

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In my Grails App, I have bootstrapped an object of a domain class as:

```
def user1 = new Users(userID: 1, name: "John Doe")
            user1.save()
```

In my dashboard controller i have retrieved the object and modified its property name as:

```
Users userObj = Users.get((Long) 1)
println(userObj as JSON); // This gives me: {"class":"com.prabin.domains.Users","id":1,"name":"John Doe"}
userObj.name = "anonymous"
```

Now i create a new Users object to retrieve the changed object with same ID 1 as

```
Users otherUserObj = Users.get((Long) 1) // **Line 2** Is this retrieving from database or from GORM session?
print(otherUserObj as JSON)// This gives me: {"class":"com.prabin.domains.Users","id":1,"name":"anonymous"}
```

But the value of object in database is not changed. And even when i retrieve the Users object of same id 1 in another controller it gives me the initial object rather than the modified as:

```
Users userObjAtDifferentController = Users.get(1);
print(userObjAtDifferentController) //This gives me: {"class":"com.prabin.domains.Users","id":1,"name":"John Doe"}
```

My question is, if the value is not changed in the database, why it gives me the modified object at **Line 2** though i have retrieved the object using GORM query (which i guess should retrieve from the database)?

I have also tried using save() after the modification but the result is same.

```
userObj.save() //doesn't show the changes in database.
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the object is not being saved to the database because some constraint(s) are invalid. You can determine whether this is the case by replacing your calls to `save()` with `save(failOnError: true)`. If my guess is correct, an exception will be thrown if saving to the database fails.

Comment: My confusion exactly is, if the values are not saved in the database, why it retrieved me the changed object at the same controller even though i retrieved a new instance. Is that the GORM Query didnt hit the database?, Is there just a proxy like class in between, which was not persisted in the database?

Comment: The object is stored in the Hibernate session until the session is flushed. This typically happens at the end of a request

Answer (score 1):

When you call the save() method on a domain object, it may not persist in the database immediately. In order to persist the changed value to the database, you would need to do the following.

```
userObj.save(flush: true)
```

By using flush, you are telling GORM to persist immediately in the database.

In some cases when validation fails, the data will still not persist in the database. The save() method will fail silently. To catch validation errors as well as save to the database immediately, you would want to do the following

```
userObj.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
```

If validation errors exist, then the GROM will throw ValidationException (http://docs.grails.org/latest/api/grails/validation/ValidationException.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider two things:

1. If you do `save()`, it only retains in hibernate session, until you flush it the changes does not persist in database. So, better do `save(flush:true, failOnError: true)` and put in `try/catch` block and print exception.
2. And another important things is, your method in `controller` needs to be with `@Transactional` annotation, without it your changes does not persist in database, you will encounter `Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed.` exception.

Hope this helps, let me know if your issue is fixed. Happy coding . :)

Comment: Thanks brother, i realized that the object is just saved in hibernate session which has per servlet scope. Thanks it really helped me.